# Get position of string from "right to left"

Tags: regex, python-2.7, function, find

it's me again.

This time I need help for find the position of a string, but from right to left.

Ex:

1. The new car is: > SUV Ford (user file: **1191.jpg**), OK ;)
2. Failure was in battery: >> Pickup Chevrolet (user file: **23.jpg**), BAD :'(
3. The new car is: > SUV Kia (user file: **8.jpg**), OK ;)
4. The new car is: > SUV Toyota (user file: **27411058.jpg**), OK ;)
5. Failure was in battery: >>> SUV Dodge (user file: **9409.jpg**), BAD, Priority

So, I'd like get the position of **'NUMBER.jpg'**, but from right to left:

1. Index #: 8 --> right to left
2. Index #: 10 --> right to left
3. Index #: 8 --> right to left
4. Index #: 8 --> right to left
5. Index #: 16 --> right to left

How can I do it in python 2.7?

@dot.Py Where are you? I need your support.

Comment: Pseudocode:    length(FullString) - StartOfMatch_LeftToRight + length(MatchedString)

Comment: Can you to translate it to python 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime you don't get other "pythonic" answers, here's a total "hack":

```
import re
print re.search("gpj", line[::-1]).start() # "gpj" as it reads in reverse
```

or, the pseudocode G5W mentioned may be something like this:

```
import re
match = "jpg"
pos = re.search(match, line).start()
print len(line) - pos - len(match)
```

either way, should get:

```
8
10
8
8
16
```

Comment: Cool!

Now I will post other topic and I hope you can help me.

Thanks bro.

Comment: Welcome, will be glad to help anytime!

Answer (score 0):

Result is in capture group 1.

Starts from the end (far right) and backtracks until it finds it.
This is the fastest way it can be done (engines optimize this for speed).

`.*((?<!\d)\d+\.jpg)`

Expanded

```
 .* 
 (                             # (1 start)
      (?<! \d )
      \d+ 
      \. jpg 
 )                             # (1 end)
```

Comment: @frankam - What is interesting ?